# MS SQL Ошибка при преобразовании типа данных varchar к numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

Пытаюсь вставить значения в таблицу, и постоянно ошибка.

> Сообщение 8114, уровень 16, состояние 5, строка 152
>   Ошибка при преобразовании типа данных varchar к numeric.

```
INSERT INTO SGROUP(GrpNo, DepNo, Course, Num, Quantity, Curator) 
VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 101, 33, 4),
(2, 1, 1, 102, 35, 4),
(3, 3, 2, 205, 20, 1),
(4, 3, 3, 305, 25, NULL),
(5, 3, 4, 405, 25, 2);
```

**Таблица**

```
CREATE TABLE SGROUP (
GrpNo int PRIMARY KEY,
DepNo int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(DepNo)
ON DELETE SET NULL,
Course numeric (1),
Num numeric (3),
Quantity numeric(2),
Curator int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TEACHER(TchNo)
ON DELETE SET NULL,
CONSTRAINT check_quantity CHECK (Quantity IN ('[1-50]%')),
CONSTRAINT check_course CHECK (Course IN ('1','2','3','4','5')),
CONSTRAINT uq_den_num UNIQUE (DepNo, Num));
```

Comment: Поле Quantity числовое. Строку `[1-50]%` привести к числу невозможно

Comment: А как тогда задать диапазон вводимых значений от 1-50?

Comment: Например `Quantity between 1 and 50`

Comment: Спасибо огромное вам. Просто лучший.

Comment: `Course IN ('1','2','3','4','5')` тоже не мешало бы в нормальный вид без кавычек привести

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Спасибо за дельное замечание, исправил.